# Can't Scroll on mobile due to image zoom on hover

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I am trying to solve a problem here. I have my own shopify store and before launching I am trying to fix a problem. I cannot zoom past image due to hover effect on images. If I try to scroll I end up zooming the image.

I am using a Fastor Theme on shopify.

There is an option in theme options which says "Enable Image Zoom". Turning it on and off doesn't make any difference. I tried understanding the code but its way beyond my understanding. Could you please help?
If the solution is in the code, please explain it. I Might be able to understand.

You can visit this product page on your phone and try to scroll. You will know what is the problem
https://endurethreads.com/products/yoga-halter-neck-sleeveless-tank-top